# Как индексировать в поиске динамические страницы?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, индексация

Есть главная страница сайта `index.php` с `<div id="content"></div>`, в который по ссылкам через javascript подгружаются разные страницы, контент для которых берётся из базы данных. Фактически получается, что пользователь остаётся на одной странице. Как можно сделать, чтобы поисковый робот видел и индексировал загружаемые страницы?

Answer (score 1):

Никак.
Только отдельные контентные страницы.

Answer (score 1):

На каждую страницу, которую вы хотите проиндексировать делается отдельный url, по которому выдается страница с уникальным содержимым.

При подзагрузке страниц через JS динамически меняйте URL страницы (window.history.pushState) после получения и отображения новых данных.

Также проверяем, чтобы сервер сразу выдавал загружаемую страницу при прямом запросе этого url (а не инициировал AJAX для выполнения подзагрузки).